# Google maps in offline mode in android applications?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps

I any one guide me to display google maps in offline mode and also get longitude and latitude for particular location in offline mode.Please give some tutorials or give some guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want tutorials for the google map v2 ?

Comment: Hello guys if u don't know leave the the question as it is, don't close the question.Close the question is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about accessing maps in offline mode. Afaik it is not possible, but someone may have an option for that.

I can however tell you that getting the longlat does not require a net connection or google, just javascript and some form of geolocation device on the unit in question.

```
if (navigator.geolocation !== undefined) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    }
}
```

It isn't a failproof solution as some units (such as the Kindle Fire) don't have any kind of geolocation device and still work with that code which is annoying.

Comment: Thanks u so much,i think this is java script code right

Comment: Sorry. Yes, it is javascript.